# non-exclusive node labels in hadoop 2.7.2 doesn't work

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am using Node Labels in hadoop 2.7.2 using https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/NodeLabel.html. but when I try to make labels non-exclusive By the command
   yarn rmadmin -addToClusterNodeLabels "label_1(exclusive=false),label_2(exclusive=false)"
it says " label name should only contains {0-9, a-z, A-Z, -, _} ...".
is it supported in hadoop 2.7.2?